# Вывести строку соответствующую условию

Tags: c#, winforms, linq

Дана строка: `тест|5 проверка|2 проверка` (подобных строк много)

Как вывести **полностью строку** соответствующую `LINQ` операции: цифра из **второго** сегмента `>= 5`

Пример:

```
тест|1 проверка
тест|5 проверка
тест|4 проверка
тест|8 проверка
```

Результат:

```
тест|5 проверка
тест|8 проверка
```

Нужен вариант с помощью `LINQ` операций.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ну например так:

```
var s = "тест|5 проверка|2 проверка";
Console.WriteLine(
    string.Concat(
        s.SkipWhile(c => c != '|') // пропустить первый сегмент
         .Skip(1)                  // попустить разделитель
         .TakeWhile(c => c != '|') // взять только второй сегмент
         .Where(char.IsDigit)      // отфильтровать цифры
         .Select(c => int.Parse(c.ToString())) // перевести в числа
         .Where(n => n >= 5)));    // отфильтровать те, которые не меньше пяти
```

---

Для случая возврата целой строки тоже просто:

```
var lines = new[]
{
    "тест|5 проверка|2 проверка",
    "тест|1 проверка",
    "тест|5 проверка",
    "тест|4 проверка",
    "тест|8 проверка"
};

Console.WriteLine(string.Join("\n",
    lines.Where(
        line => line.SkipWhile(c => c != '|')
                    .Skip(1)
                    .TakeWhile(c => c != '|')
                    .Where(char.IsDigit)
                    .Select(c => int.Parse(c.ToString()))
                    .Any(n => n >= 5))));
```

Comment: Спасибо за ответ, но т.к я эту проблему решил буквально за минуту после создания темы, то я изменил свой вопрос в теме. За вариант спасибо, свой выкину, ваш более правильный.

Comment: @Максим: То есть у вас теперь на входе _набор строк_?

Comment: Почему теперь? Их и в предыдущем вопросе было много (в первом посте написано). Просто мн сейчас нужно вывести всю строку, если результат соответствует `>= 5`

Comment: Спасибо большое.

Comment: @Максим: Пожалуйста! Надеюсь, что помогло.